# ODBC Security Risk

Tags: excel, database, postgresql, connection, odbc

community

*This is my first question so please don't mind if something is not right...*

**What I want:**
I would like to connect an Excel-Sheet with a postgres-database directly through a ODBC-Driver. The idea is that the Excel-Sheet should update all the data automatically by just clicking "Refresh Data".

I want to avoid the manual steps (execute the sql-query, export the result/data, import to Excel, format the data) before analyzing the data.

**Problem/Issue/Questions:**

1. Is there any security risk with the ODBC (Credentials/Connections etc.)?
2. Is it recommended to install an ODBC-driver?
3. Is there any alternative?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I haven't use postgres but I've used the sqlLite and SQL Server ODBC connectors for many years. Both were a royal pain in the ass to get working but when I finally [messed around](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a8112776%20odbc) enough to get them working, I'd have no further issues.  My issues mostly seemed to revolve around the OEM connector software being designed for 32bit Windows and me being on 64bit.  As for security, I've never had or heard of any ODBC-related security issues involving Microsoft Office [yet!]

Comment: Related reading from Microsoft: [Administer ODBC data sources](https://support.microsoft.com/office/administer-odbc-data-sources-b19f856b-5b9b-48c9-8b93-07484bfab5a7)

Comment: Hi ashleedawg, thank you for your help! I've read that the password in the Excel-Sheet could be seen and therefore it is a very high risk issue. But I'm not sure about this. That's why I need clearifications about the possible risk issues that comes with using the ODBC.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.